# Recursive delete of multiple rows in one table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-delete, recursive-query

I have a problem with my postgres database. I have a table `Tasks` with 3 columns: ID, Name and Parent_ID (which refers to another task id in this table):

```
id | name | parent_id 
---+------+-----------
 1 | A    |     0
 2 | B    |     1
 3 | C    |     2
 4 | D    |     1
 5 | E    |     0
 6 | F    |     0
```

So basically it's like this:

```
1. A
2.     B
3.          C
4.     D
5. E
6. F
```

What I'm trying to do is to delete task A, and delete all of its children and all children of children etc etc..(in this case B and D, along with C as its children of B which is deleted) something like cascade delete, but i cant do this. Maybe any function will work?

The result after delete should be

```
id | name | parent_id
---+------+-----------
 5 | E    |     0
 6 | F    |     0
```

Hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 3):

You only need a cascading FK-constraint:

---

```
\i tmp.sql

CREATE TABLE employees (
   id serial PRIMARY KEY
   , name VARCHAR NOT NULL
   , parent_id INT REFERENCES employees(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

INSERT INTO employees
VALUES (1,'A', NULL),(2,'B', 1),(3,'C', 2),
       (4,'D', 1),(5,'E', NULL),(6,'F', NULL);

DELETE FROM employees
WHERE name = 'A'
        ;

SELECT * FROM employees
        ;


----------

Result:

----------

    DROP SCHEMA
    CREATE SCHEMA
    SET
    CREATE TABLE
    INSERT 0 6
    DELETE 1
     id | name | parent_id 
    ----+------+-----------
      5 | E    |          
      6 | F    |          
    (2 rows)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can build the list of all descendent rows from the starting name with a recursive query, and then use it as a filter for the deletetions.

```
with recursive cte(id, parent_id) as (
    select id, parent_id from mytable where name = 'A'
    union all
    select t.id, t.parent_id from mytable t inner join cte c on c.id = t.parent_id
)
delete from mytable where id in (select id from cte)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=68d5ffd61c23ebfe2d2dcdefb4f3bb55)** - table content after executing the query:

```
id | name | parent_id
-: | :--- | --------:
 5 | E    |         0
 6 | F    |         0
```

Comment: It works fine, thanks, but what if ID is put as foreign key in another table? it forbids me to delete as it infracts foreign key from another table (i want to delete those rows from this table aswell). To be precise, this second table contains materials used for certain tasks. So each task ID in second table have its own material in a single row. I tried doing transaction, or one delete after one delete, or even tried to somehow join those both tables but it doesn't work.

Comment: @fufuj: you need to delete from the children table first, then from the main table. You can use the same query, just change the target table and column name in the final `delete` statement: `delete from << mytable >> where << id >> in (select id from cte)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use recursive cte to get all rows with Name = 'A' and it's subordinates.
Then delete it from table employees.

Here is the step to create the table:

```
Sample table: CREATE TABLE employees (
   id serial PRIMARY KEY,
   name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
   parent_id INT
);

INSERT INTO employees 
VALUES (1,'A', 0),(2,'B', 1),(3,'C', 2),
       (4,'D', 1),(5,'E', 0),(6,'F', 0);
```

Query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE subordinates AS (
   SELECT
      id,
      parent_id,
      name
   FROM
      employees
   WHERE
      name = 'A'
   UNION
      SELECT
         e.id,
         e.parent_id,
         e.name
      FROM
         employees e
      INNER JOIN subordinates s ON s.id = e.parent_id
) 
DELETE 
FROM employees
WHERE id in (
  SELECT
    id
  FROM
   subordinates);

SELECT * FROM employees;
```